# Проблема с приседанием

Tags: unity3d

Привет. Есть такой скрипт:

```
 float localHeight = CharHeight;
    if (_PlayerMode == PlayerMode.Crouch)
    {
        localHeight = CharHeight * 0.5F;
    }
    float lastHeight = Controller.height;
    Controller.height = Mathf.Lerp(Controller.height, localHeight, 5 * Time.deltaTime);
    CharTransform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + (Controller.height - lastHeight) / 2, transform.position.z); //Fix vertical position CharTransform = transform.
```

Думаю у многих была проблема, что при таком методе реализации приседаний, камера двигалась не до конца, а на половину где-то от роста Character`a. Получается, нужно анимацию делать для камеры? И при создании анимации учитывать что она всё таки немного будет двигаться?

Comment: а если по-русски? какие приседания? причем тут приседания? `при таком методе реализации приседаний, камера двигалась не до конца` - какого конца? двигалась куда?

Comment: Как видно из скрипта, приседание - это изменение высоты контроллера . Когда контроллер приседает(меняет свою высоту), то камера вниз двигается не до конца. Вообщем, если не понятно, могу записать видео.

Comment: Если хотите помощи, опишите полностью свой вопрос. Из скрипта не видно ничего, кроме того что там написано. Ни как закреплена камера, ни что такое "конец", к которому она должна двигаться, ни что такое приседание, ни-че-го. К тому же, никому не хочется вчитываться в чужой код, не зная для чего.

Comment: Тогда вот - https://youtu.be/8ZCK2K1re7A

Comment: В стандартном состоянии камера находится в Capsule Collider, но когда я выполняю скрипт она двигается за контроллером немного вниз и в итоге выходит за грани колайдера. В иерархии камера прикрепленна к контроллеру.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Персонаж до приседания. Камера привязана к верху капсулы
2. Сжимание капсулы на персонаже. Капсула все еще наверху старого положения.
3. Опускание персонажа на землю, чтобы пивот снова касался основания капсулы( 25% от капсулы). Камера опускается на туже величину. То есть камера опускается на 25% от капсулы вместо нужных 50%(половине капсулы)
4. То как должно быть. Камеру нужно опустить также на 50%, а не 25%

Это же очевидно невооруженным глазом. Сдвигай центр капсулы, а не пивот, и камеру крепи за верхнюю границу капсулы.

Comment: Что то типа такого:
`        Controller.center = new Vector3(Controller.center.x, Controller.center.y + (Controller.height - lastHeight) / 2, Controller.center.z); 
`?
С этим вариантом контроллер также гладко меняет рост но камера вообще не изменяет позицию. Центр Y в минус уходит.
"камеру крепи за верхнюю границу капсулы." Я так понял это кодом нужно делать? Просто когда через инспектор меняю центр, то камера движется, а если кодом то нет.

Comment: Всё. Разобрался. Добавил - эту строчку `        PlayerCamTransfrom.transform.position = new Vector3(PlayerCamTransfrom.transform.position.x, PlayerCamTransfrom.transform.position.y + (Controller.height - lastHeight), PlayerCamTransfrom.transform.position.z);
`

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону `[Cinemachine][1]` - бесплатного ассета от Unity. Он дает много возможностей для того чтобы настроить камеру для наблюдателя. Есть поддержка мертвых зон, плавного наблюдения, случайного дрожания (например при удержании в руках) и многое другое.